# What is this feature in Sublime called and how do I disable it?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

When I type this:

```
<div>
</
```

Sublime automatically writes this:

```
<div>
</div>
```

It's annoying because I usually write like this:

```
<div>
<>
```

And then go inside the brackets and fill the tag out, but as soon as I type `/`, Sublime does this:

```
<div>
</div>>
```

Very non-intuitive and specific to certain habits of certain coders (which could easily be resolved by checking to see if a `>` is already present).

Anyway, how can I disable this automation? `"auto_complete": false` didn't do it.

Comment: Have you tried Textedit.app or Notepad.exe? I believe they suit this type of workflow.

Comment: I would love to use Sublime if I could just resolve this one issue.

Comment: All good mate, just a tongue in cheek comment. You have an odd style which very few people would follow. May I ask what benefit you get out of doing it this way? The problem I could see is you could potentially leave an ominous "<>" tag laying around when forgotten about.

Comment: I also write both parentheses before I write the content inside them. It's going to absolutely be required without any volatility at the end so I just write it now. Also, the likelihood of leaving a `<>` laying around is no more likely than forgetting a closing `"`.

Comment: You know you can do HTML code completion like this, right? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyc2-C_rEkM (26 sec video I made you). Find more here: http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/. The pull of Sublimetext for most people is creating the key bindings that suit you are dead simple.

Comment: Honestly I find coding everything by hand is easier than getting accustomed to syntax that will only work under certain circumstances. Syntax highlighting and (usually) automatic indentation are the only advantages I'm comfortable coding with. Everything else just seems to overcomplicate really simple tasks, I'm also really particular with how the raw code appears, and automated things like this and things like Sass take some liberty when generating their code (inconsistent indentation for example). It's so insignificant and stupid, but it bothers me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags are automatically being closed on you. To disable this, add the following User settings:

```
"auto_close_tags": false
```

The `auto_complete` setting is specifically referring to the completion popup window that you see as you type. So you probably want this to remain enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Auto complete can be disabled with the auto_complete setting. To disable it, add this line to Preferences/File Settings - User:

"auto_complete": false

Comment: I tried that, but it just removed the drop-down menu that shows up when you start typing. Maybe this is just a premanent feature in Sublime?

Comment: @user2840753 Remove your `auto_complete: false` setting. You only want the `auto_complete: false` setting.

Comment: True, but I wanted that feature removed as well. :)